# Can't upgrade from ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, 21.10, 22.04

When I type in

`pkexec do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE`

I get error

````
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
kde
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 253, in <module>
    fetcher = get_fetcher(options.frontend, m.new_dist, options.data_dir)
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 43, in get_fetcher
    progress = KDEAcquireProgressAdapter(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeFetcherKDE.py", line 190, in __init__
    uic.loadUi(uiFile, self.dialog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/__init__.py", line 238, in loadUi
    return DynamicUILoader(package).loadUi(uifile, baseinstance, resource_suffix)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/Loader/loader.py", line 66, in loadUi
    return self.parse(filename, resource_suffix)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/uiparser.py", line 1020, in parse
    document = parse(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1229, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 569, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/ubuntu-release-upgrader/fetch-progress.ui'```
````

Comment: I get the same error while trying to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 (LTS).